# cron tab to restart my delayed_job server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, delayed-job

I want to create a cront tab to restart my delayed_job server if it breaks.

how may check that my delayed_job server is running or not with ps command?

how may i create a cron tab to check this thing work? Like if my server break than cron tab will restart it. I want to set cront tab to check it every 5 minute.

Comment: Overseen today, maybe relevant http://dustin.github.com/2010/02/28/running-processes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my script which check if pid files is created or not. If pid file is not exist than it will start the delayed_job server.
I have created my script in my application root folder
This is my script delayed_job.sh

```
if ! [ -s delayed_job.pids ]; then
  RAILS_ENV=production /app/script/delayed_job start
end
```

And i have set this script on crontab like this.

```
*/5 * * * * RAILS_ENV=production /bin/bash /app/delayed_job.sh
```

It's working fine. If i break delayed_job server than it will automatically start my delayed_job server. Is it a proper way??

Comment: In a lot of cases, my pids are still running and available, it's just that DJ is not processing any jobs and needs to be restarted. Any recommendations for seeing how and calling them out when they're choking?

Comment: I found that in my case I would sometimes end up with multiple copies of delayed_job running (and none of them doing anything) with this approach. I fixed it by adding a "pkill -u <username> -f delayed_job" to the conditional block.

Answer (score 2):

The right way if you have one delayed_job process is:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ -s #{pids_dir}/delayed_job.pid ]; then  
  RAILS_ENV=production #{RAILS_APP}/script/delayed_job start  
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [runit/sv](http://smarden.org/runit/) to manage delayed_job. Includes monitoring, auto restarts, logging.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't stick to cron, Monit may be more useful.
http://mmonit.com/monit/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. I check for whether you have a single job started or you have more than one. If you do, quit, otherwise start the job with two workers. You probably won't need that `/usr/local/bin/ruby` part.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -f /apps/gits/myapp/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid 
      && ! -f /apps/gits/myapp/tmp/pids/delayed_job.0.pid ]];
then
  echo "DJ not running" 
  cd /apps/gits/myapp
  RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/ruby script/delayed_job -n 2 start
  echo "DJ Started"
else
  echo "DJ running"
fi
```

And then my cron runs every hour, just make sure the bash is executable.

```
0 */1 * * * /apps/gits/scripts/start_dj_if_not_running.sh 
               >> /apps/gits/myapp/log/runner.log 2>&1
```